# R - Model selection in Glmer

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, model-selection

Having troubles to perform a model selection for glmer in R. I'm using the package lme4 with the following structure:

````
    glo_mo <- glmer(aban ~ year + hab + wlv + gra + cov + (1|lodge), 
              data = aban, family='binomial',
              na.action = na.omit)

    ```
str(aban)
Classes ‘spec_tbl_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    67 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ lodge  : chr  "2" "52" "34" "39" ...
 $ year   : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ hab    : chr  "for" "for" "for" "for" ...
 $ wlv    : num  7 1 NA NA 4 NA NA -4 44 NA ...
 $ dlv    : num  5 NA NA NA 7 NA NA 2 4 NA ...
 $ gra    : num  3 0 0 0 3 NA 0 8 5 4 ...
 $ cov    : num  3.92 16.46 1.78 1.25 2.48 ...
 $ for_str: num  4.4 4.06 3.65 5.54 4.14 5.69 8.61 5.84 6.23 4.36 ...
 $ aban   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 ...
````

When I run the model:

```
    summary(glo_mo)
    Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: aban ~ year + hab + wlv + gra + cov + (1 | lodge)
   Data: aban

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
    76.4     89.7    -31.2     62.4       42 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.7283 -1.1100  0.5375  0.7449  1.4179 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 lodge  (Intercept) 0.09585  0.3096  
Number of obs: 49, groups:  lodge, 32

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -0.360995   0.824027  -0.438    0.661
year2        0.605911   0.650404   0.932    0.352
habstep     -0.340842   0.926110  -0.368    0.713
wlv          0.005414   0.009677   0.559    0.576
gra          0.032089   0.086737   0.370    0.711
cov          0.023428   0.022942   1.021    0.307

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr) year2  habstp wlv    gra   
year2   -0.239                            
habstep -0.470  0.033                     
wlv     -0.127 -0.051 -0.155              
gra     -0.666 -0.130  0.411  0.313       
cov     -0.130 -0.074 -0.647  0.185 -0.170
```

Then, I tried to standarize and use the function dredge to automatically  select best models, but this last one did not work. The following error mistake

```
stad <- standardize(glo_mo, standardize.y=F)
options(na.action = "na.fail")
mset <- dredge(stad)

Error in dredge(glo_mo) : 'global.model' uses 'na.action' = "na.omit"
```

So that blocks me to continue to the selection model. Based on my previous steps and with the aim to select best models, 
1. What is wrong in my script?

2. Also, Is AIC the only parameter to select the best models? Do I have to run each of the model combinations to select the best one, or can I apply function dredge or steps to do that?
3. What are the other options to select best models in glmer with lme4(or other recommend it packages)?

Comment: The error message seems to be due to a discrepancy in your handling of NA values (na.omit for the glo_mo model, na.fail for the dredge function call), a software issue that is off topic on this statistics-oriented site. What is on-topic is the danger of any attempt at automated model selection, noted with respect to the dredge function [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/254757/28500) and in many other threads with the [model-selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-selection) tag.

Comment: @EdM - I think that could be an answer, if you expand it a little. Do you want to do that?  If not, I will try.

Comment: I am voting to leave this open as there seems to be a large statistical aspect to it.

Comment: @PeterFlom-ReinstateMonica I implemented your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have too few observations to include in your initial model that many predictors. Also, note that for binary data the effective sample size is determined by the minimum of the frequencies of the zeros and the ones. Hence, you have very little information in your data to obtain any meaningfully stable results.

Finally, as noted in the comments by EdM, model selection, especially with that small sample size, can be very dangerous. It would be best to just report the results from your full model.

Answer (score 2):

1. Although this software-specific question is technically off-topic here, I do note that NA values were handled differently in the two calls: `na.omit` for the glo_mo model, `na.fail` for the dredge function call.
2. AIC and BIC are discussed in detail on [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/577/28500). There is some dispute about whether these approaches are correct for comparing the non-nested models you would evaluate in approaches like `dredge` uses. I'm not an expert on that, see [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/116935/28500) for an introduction.
3. Purely automated model selection is generally [to be avoided](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20836/28500), particularly when there is subject-matter knowledge available to guide your model building. Note that in logistic regression there is a [danger in omitting *any* predictor that is expected to be related to outcome](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/113766/28500). The problem you face, as noted in the answer from Dimitris Rizopoulos, is that you do not have enough cases to evaluate 5 predictors plus the random-effect term. The usual rule of thumb for logistic regression is [10-20 members of the minority class per predictor that you are evaluating](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/307642/28500) unless you are using some type of penalization. If you have 67 total observations then you have at most 33 members of the minority class. You could consider ridge regression to include all predictors with penalization to avoid overfitting. If you insist on a model-selection strategy, then you should validate your model-building approach by repeating all steps *including the predictor-selection steps* on multiple bootstrap samples from your data, and testing performance of each bootstrap-derived model on the full data set.